# Maven antrun plugin set property based on OS

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I am converting an ant script to Maven and decided to use Maven ant run plugin. I am on the good way, but I hit the following problem. Ant source script uses target definition as follows:

```
<condition property="isWindows">
  <os family="windows"/>
</condition>
<condition property="isUnix">
  <os family="unix"/>
</condition>


<target name="init-windows" depends="" if="isWindows">
  <property file="${user.home}/abc.properties"/>
</target>

<target name="init-unix" depends="" if="isUnix">
 <property name="abc.home" value="${env.ABC_HOME}"/>
</target>
```

The point is to use property value

> abc.home

later in the build cycle which is dependent on OS (Win,Linux).
In the ant script it is ok,but maven ant run plugin does not enable using the multiple targets. I do not want to use Maven profile tags. I would like to use ant tag for this if there is any? Does anybody have a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think an easier solution would be *not* to use the `maven-antrun-plugin` and use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) instead.

Profiles are a good way to have a different of properties depending of some activation property. One of those activation property can be the OS which is running the build.

Consider the following POM:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>windows</id>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>windows</family>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <!-- Associate the read-project-properties goal with the initialize phase, to read the properties file. -->
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>${user.home}/abc.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>unix</id>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>unix</family>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <abc.home>${env.ABC_HOME}</abc.home>
    <properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

- When run on a Windows machine, the `windows` profile will be activated. Reading a property file is done with the `properties-maven-plugin` and its content will be placed in properties, just like the Ant `<property>` task.
- When run on an Unix machine, the `unix` profile will be activated and the `abc.home` property will be set to `${env.ABC_HOME}`.

Then, in your Maven build, you can use `${abc.home}` without having to worry in which profile you are in.

---

Having said that, another solution would be to run multiple executions of the `maven-antrun-plugin`. In the first execution, you decide whether the build in running in a Windows or Unix machine and then skip the following executions accordingly. This would be a sample configuration, where `myPhase` would be the phase you want this to run.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>myphase</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <condition property="isWindows">
                        <os family="windows" />
                    </condition>
                    <condition property="isUnix">
                        <os family="unix" />
                    </condition>
                </target>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>myphase</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target name="init-windows" depends="">
                    <property file="${user.home}/abc.properties" />
                </target>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                <skip>${isUnix}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>myphase</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target name="init-unix" depends="">
                    <property name="abc.home" value="${env.ABC_HOME}" />
                </target>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                <skip>${isWindows}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I implemented the first concept to have it more mavenized.